# How to pull data from two CTEs in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I'm trying to pull current ytd sales and prior ytd sales for the same period. I have the SQL that pulls the data correctly (separately), but I don't know how to put it together in a CTE, or if that is even the best way to do it. Here is what I have so far:

```
with current_year AS 
(
SELECT 
    SUM(TOTAL_REVENUE_USD) AS CURRENT_YEAR_REVENUE
FROM 
    FACT_ORDER
WHERE 
    year(COMMISSION_DATE) = year(current_date)
),

prior_year AS 
(
SELECT 
    SUM(TOTAL_REVENUE_USD) AS PRIOR_YEAR_REVENUE
FROM   
    FACT_ORDER
WHERE 
    COMMISSION_DATE BETWEEN date_from_parts((date_part(year,current_date())-1),1,1) 
    AND dateadd(year,-1,current_date());
)
```

I've tried using CTEs (see the above code), but I am stuck. I don't know where to go from here. I would like the result to be something like:

```
2022   $10,000,000
2023   $11,000,000
```

SAMPLE DATA:
[image]

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input table and expected output?

Comment: Skip the cte's. Simply GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want an `union`:

```sql
select * 
from current_year
union all
select *
from previous year
```

But since the CTEs are missing the column `year`:

```sql
select 2023 year, * 
from current_year
union all
select 2022, *
from previous year
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was going to be more complicated than that. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem! I would maybe start from 0 instead and forget about the CTEs. Just a `select sum(total_revenue), year from orders where year>... group by year`. The only complication is the subtly different definition of year depending on what is the current date